# What do AssemblyVersion autoincrementing numbers mean?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, version-control, build

Following the recommendations in system generated comments of an AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

I set (just for testing):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.1.*")]
```

After building, I get the version number: `2.1.4321.42563`
Then, after making small change to the AssemblyInfo.cs file and building once more, I get next version:  `2.1.4321.42710`

I'm wondering what do all that numbers (*4321.42563*; *4321.42710*) mean? **What is the pattern, following which the system generates them?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4321 = number of days since January 1st 2000
42563 = number of seconds since midnight / 2

Which makes that 10/31/2011 11:38:46 PM.  It is local time without daylight savings adjustment.

Comment: Note: this is only true if you wildcard build and revision i.e. [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")], if you specify build manually and only wildcard revision i.e. [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")] you'll get a random revision

Comment: Hmm, that is a bug.  No guarantee whatsoever that you get a distinct version number.  Particularly tricky on a build server that is apt to kick-off a build at set time intervals.  Never do this.

Answer (score 2):

The build number is an indication of the day it was build, the revision number is random by documentation but in reality, right now, as Hans specifies.

> You can specify all the values or you can accept the default build
>   number, revision number, or both by using an asterisk (*). For
>   example, [assembly:AssemblyVersion("2.3.25.1")] indicates 2 as the
>   major version, 3 as the minor version, 25 as the build number, and 1
>   as the revision number. A version number such as
>   [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")] specifies 1 as the major version,
>   2 as the minor version, and accepts the default build and revision
>   numbers. A version number such as
>   [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")] specifies 1 as the major
>   version, 2 as the minor version, 15 as the build number, and accepts
>   the default revision number. **The default build number increments
>   daily. The default revision number is random.**

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually, I have made the observation that  [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.15.*")] will result in a random revision number while [assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")] will result in the deterministic pattern that Hans described (build = days since 2000, rev = twin seconds since midnight)